# NHibernate Criteria Find by Id

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

I have 2 entities:

```
public class Authority : Entity
{
    [NotNull, NotEmpty]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public virtual AuthorityType Type { get; set; }

}

public class AuthorityType : Entity
{
    [NotNull, NotEmpty]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now I wish to find all authorities from repository by type. I tried doing it like this:

```
    public IList<Authority> GetAuthoritiesByType(int id)
    {
        ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Authority));
        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Type.Id", id));
        IList<Authority> authorities = criteria.List<Authority>();
        return authorities;            
    }
```

However, I'm getting an error that something is wrong with the SQL ("could not execute query". The innerexception is following: {"Invalid column name 'TypeFk'.\r\nInvalid column name 'TypeFk'."}

Any advice ? Any other approach ?

Best wishes,
Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your mapping file for the Authority entity is associating the `Type` property to a column named `TypeFk` in whatever table that the Authority entity is mapped to. For some reason, that column is not there.

It might be helpful to see your mapping files too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to right direction. I'm using Fluent and I had mapped ForeignKeyConvention incorrectly.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Maybe you can help a brutha out and vote up and mark answered? You know, it impresses women... and I need all the help I can get. :P

Comment: Haha - here's a point to help you score with all the foxy girls here that get off on a guy's big rep